# R Find changes in values of a column sequentially and count them for entire matrix of data

Tags: r

I have a large matrix like this:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    9    4    2    1   NA    7
[2,]    9    5    1    1    1    7
[3,]    3    5    1    5   NA   10
[4,]    9    4    2   14   NA    7
[5,]   18    4    4   24   NA   10
[6,]   24    5    4   30   NA   10
[7,]    6    3    1   31    1   10
[8,]    2    5    4   34    1    7
[9,]    4    5    2   34   NA    7
[10,]   4    5    2   34   NA    7
```

I count how many changes I have from 7 to 10 in the 6th column. But I count pairwise. For example it is only allowed to count each row only once (more precise the number in the 4th column must appear only once). Now in addition, I want to know if both values in the 5th row equal 1.

Let's do an example with the given matrix above:
I have a change in the 6th column from 7 to 10 in the rows 2 to 3. Therefore the count = 1. Next I have again a change from row 3 to 4. But since row 3 cannot be counted twice this change will not be counted (in other words in column 5 the value 5 would appear twice in my countings, which is not allowed).

Next I count a change from row 4 to 5: count = count + 1. Hence, count = 2 up until now. The next change would be from row 7 to row 8. In row 7 and in row 8 the values in the 5th column equal 1. Therefore I would get at the end:

```
count = 3
```

and thereof one pair has 1's in the fifth column:

```
countl = 1
```

Has anyone a suggestion how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do a for-loop. Pseudocode:

```
counter <- 0
evaluate <- 1  # 1 means yes, evaluate the next pair, 0 means no
for (i in 1:nrow(matrix)) {
    if(evaluate == 1) {
        if(matrix[i,6] == matrix[i+1,6]) {
            counter <- counter + 1
            evaluate <- 0
        }
    } else {
        evaluate <- 1
    }
}
```

This code does not work as is but will give you an idea how to handle your problem.

Replace "matrix" with the handle of your matrix (e.g. "dat") and check if `dat[i+1,6]` works, if not do `j <- i + 1` and `dat[i,6] == dat[j,6]`.

Answer (score 0):

May be one way of doing it.

Data:

```
dput(mat1)
structure(c(9L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 18L, 24L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 14L, 24L, 30L, 31L, 34L, 34L, 34L, NA, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 7L, 7L, 10L, 7L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
7L, 7L, 7L), .Dim = c(10L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6")))
```

Function:
myfunc function checks for these things:

1. If all values in a vector is NA or having NA with one unique value, then it returns 0
2. Else:

   a) Remove NA from the vector and assign it to variable 'x'

   b) Remove the index of 'x' that has a sequence of same values (Eg: 7,7,7,10, 10, 10), but keep the index where ever there is a difference in the value (Eg: 7,10) and assign to 'a1' variable

   c) If length of 'a1' is greater than 3, apply the statements within its block

   d) Else, checks for length of a1 is 3 or 2 or 1 or less than 0 and applies the statements with in its block. If a condition is true, then its returns the value in its block.

   ```
   myfunc <- function(x){
     if(length(unique(x[which(!is.na(x))])) <= 1){
       return(0)
     }else {
      x = x[which(!is.na(x))]
      a1 = which(diff(x) != 0)

        if(length(a1) > 3){
           b1 = a1[seq(1, length(a1), 2)]
           b2 = a1[seq(2, length(a1), 2)]
           return(length(b1) + sum(diff(b2) != 2))
        } else {
              if(length(a1) == 3){
                 count3 = sum(diff(a1) == 1)
                 if(count3 == 1 || count3 == 2){
                    return(2)
                 }else if(count3 == 0) {
                    return(3)
                 }
              }else if(length(a1) == 2){
                  if(diff(a1) == 1){
                     return(1)
                  }else{
                     return(2)
                  }
              }else if(length(a1) == 1){
                  return(1)
              }else {
                  return(0)
              }
         }
      }
   }
   ```

Apply Function to data 'mat1':

```
count = apply(mat1, 2, myfunc)

print(count)
# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 
#  4  4  4  3  0  3
```

Modify Data by adding 'NA' to 3rd row and 6th column

```
mat1[3,6] = NA

mat1
# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
# [1,]  9  4  2  1 NA  7
# [2,]  9  5  1  1  1  7
# [3,]  3  5  1  5 NA NA
# [4,]  9  4  2 14 NA  7
# [5,] 18  4  4 24 NA 10
# [6,] 24  5  4 30 NA 10
# [7,]  6  3  1 31  1 10
# [8,]  2  5  4 34  1  7
# [9,]  4  5  2 34 NA  7
# [10,]  4  5  2 34 NA  7
```

Apply Function to modified data

```
count = apply(mat1, 2, myfunc)

print(count)
# V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 
# 4  4  4  3  0  2
```